# Proper time of an object crossing event horizon in Kruskal coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, event-horizon

So I am reading a paper on a certain black hole paradox. The specifics actually don't matter, but if you want context (p16): [black hole thought experiment](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/9308100.pdf). An object falls into a black hole. The observer is waiting outside the event horizon for a time of about $\tau \sim M^3$ with M the mass of the black hole so he can read some information in the hawking radiation. He then crosses the event horizon and the thing that fell in (apparatus A) then sends a signal to the observer. It is a static black hole that they describe in Kurskal coordinates. I get the analysis, except for the part where they go calculate the proper time the apparatus has to send its message to the observer. How do they get to this result (I highlighted it at the end in "bold" text)?

> Because we work with observations made inside the event horizon we
>   introduce lightcone Kruskal coordinates that extend past the event
>   horizon.
>
> \begin{equation}   \begin{aligned}   U &= - \exp(\frac{r^* - t}{4M})\\
>  V &= \text{ }\exp(\frac{r^* + t}{4M})   \end{aligned}   \label{krusk}
>  \end{equation}
>
> The future event horizon is at U = 0 and the singularity is at UV = 1.
>   The geometry is shown in Figure 7. It is evident that the value of U
>   where the observer O runs into the singularity becomes very small if
>   the observer delays for a long time entering the black hole. This in
>   turn
>
> constrains the time which the apparatus A has available to emit its
>   message inside the event horizon. Let us choose the origin of our tortoise time coordinate so
>   that the apparatus passes through the stretched horizon at V = 1. The
>   observer O will go through the stretched horizon after a period of
>   order $M^3$ has passed in tortoise time, i. e. at $\log V ∼ M^2$ . Since the
>   singularity is at UV = 1 the message from A must be sent before the
>   apparatus reaches $U ∼ \exp (−M^2 )$. **Near V = 1 this corresponds to a
>   very short proper time  $\tau ∼ M^2 \exp(-M^2)$**.

Note: in the text they also give you the line element $ds^2 = ... dUdV$ but I doubt you need this because it is a very hard expression, you can find it online if you want.